# jQuery fade not working on iPhone Safari

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've tried using FadeToggle, FadeIn, and FadeOut, and I can get none of these to work on mobile safari, but they all work great in Firefox (which I'm using to test responsive design). This is the relevant bit of code, which is in global scope:

```
$('#swipeicon').bind("load", function () {
$(this).delay(100).fadeToggle('slow').fadeToggle('slow').fadeToggle('slow').fadeToggle('slow');
```

});

Many of the other similar issues I've seen asked about on SO and around the internet pinpoint the problem as being a position:fixed style somewhere...but nowhere do I have a position:fixed. It's completely mystifying.

I've tested the function with an alert in it and that doesn't fire. I tried an alert in $document.ready(), and that does fire on the iPhone...so jQuery is being loaded in. I really don't know what this could be or what to try. I've previously written the fadeIn/fadeOut in native JS, but can only get it to loop once on the iPhone (when I need it to loop twice, which it does perfectly on desktop). This is immensely frustrating and time-consuming.

Comment: Okay, well, I snipped out the relevant bits into their own document, and they work perfectly well on mobile safari. So clearly something else in the 800+ lines is causing the problem. :-(

Comment: Found the problem, which is this meta tag:
`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Which is unfortunate because I need this so that my media queries will work on the iPhone.

Comment: Actually nope, that's not it. I took out the bit with width=device-width, and that fixed it, one time. I reloaded the page, didn't work again. I added the meta tag to the stubbed page, and it worked just fine. I've gone through each section of styling, js, and html, and nothing seems to be causing the problem. I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: Try animating and see if that works -- demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/7nu7h0so/